# Diffing Windows .exe/.dll files

Tags: windows, dll, diff, portable-executable

Since we're storing some .dlls and some .exes in version control (don't ask...), I'd like to be able to reliably diff which files have changed between revisions. Basically, `bindiff` seems to be what I am looking for (see [tools for diffing windows binaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345815/tools-for-diffing-windows-binaries/346294) and [Deterministic builds under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180852/deterministic-builds-under-windows/1180892)), but the only download link I could find was for Windows XP (actually given in the second link).

Is `bindiff` available for Windows 7? Or is there a similar tool that can exclude PE timestamps and whatever else is in there that changes between compilations of the same files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our tool (ECMerge) has a specific Executable File Format for that, it declares a field "PE Header Timestamp" which can be ignored in comparison options. If it is not enough in your case, it is possible to increase the capabilities of the file format through scripting (in JavaScript).